# Do we want to unpin the accepted answer from the top?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answers, accepted-answer

**[Stack Overflow has changed the way the answers are sorted:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/967621)**

> We no longer pin the accepted answer (with the green checkmark) to the top of the list of answers. By default, we now sort strictly by votes (descending order by highest score), and the accepted answer's order in the list is based on its score.

**There is [a question now on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/578690) if we would like to have the accepted answer unpinned on our site:**

> We can change the way the engine sorts answers in site settings. We would like to hear from you all if it is something you want to see on your site. [...] **We are going to collect feedback before the end of September 19th.**

*I am posting this question here to discuss what would work best for Coffee Stack Exchange.*

Comment: Added the [status-review] tag because the post has been up for months. Even though we've only had a few votes, I think the 1-0 vote (2-0 if you count my vote as the answerer) in favor of unpinning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(reused [my Politics Meta answer](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5978) as a template)

I looked at the data a bit using [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/coffee/query/1457440/questions-where-accepted-answers-dont-have-the-highest-score). There are 59 questions where the accepted answer is outscored by another answer. In [21 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/coffee/query/1457505/questions-where-accepted-answers-dont-have-the-highest-score-by-at-least-3-votes) the difference in score between the accepted answer and the highest scoring answer is at least 3.

Of those questions where the accepted answer is outscored, [in 2 cases](https://data.stackexchange.com/coffee/query/1457490/questions-where-negatively-scored-accepted-answers-is-outscored) the accepted answer has a negative score.

**As such, I think it makes sense to sort answers based on score only.** While it doesn't happen that often, it prevents askers from prominently featuring a poor answer at the top. For Coffee, this seems especially useful when more detailed new answers are posted and the OP has left the site.

---

The [following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/coffee/query/1459927/questions-with-2-answer-and-the-highest-scoring-answer-is-accepted) shows questions where the highest scoring answer was accepted and there's at least one other answer. This yields 304 unique questions. The score difference between the accepted answer and the second highest scoring answer ranges from 0 to 29.

In [47 cases](https://data.stackexchange.com/coffee/query/1459928/questions-with-2-answers-the-highest-scoring-answer-is-accepted-and-tied-with-a) the accepted answer has the same score as another answer. Ties are also addressed in a [feature-request](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) [on main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369569) which asks that the accepted answer is shown above other answers with the same score.

Comment: Especially here with a lot of drive-by users, that makes sense. I may use a few of your queries on other sites. I already checked the number of questions where a change in policy would make a difference, but forgot to include it in the question.

Comment: What if you use the modified SEDE query mentioned [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16089/215471)?

Comment: @user1271772 same result right? 59 questions (on Coffee).

Comment: Do you have that user's modified SEDE query by any chance?

Comment: @user1271772 I'm not sure what you mean, that query was mentioned in a comment on Arcade, it links [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/1462135). There's a search by site name field in the bottom so you can change it to other sites. The query itself is adapted to Arcade in that it hardcoded the links, but the counts are correct for any site.

Comment: The mod on that site, named Timmy Jim, says in the answer I linked to, that he modified the SEDE query.

Comment: @user1271772 I don't have the query mentioned in that answer, but that mod also linked to a query in a comment under the question. It returns some percentage, not sure what it means exactly.

Comment: I believe "accepted answer" mostly overrides the majority inclination. This is against the very nature of SE community as it uses community common sense as an exception handling mechanism.

Comment: Also, another problem is, it is obvious that some users may accept an answer on the date but did not care about it afterwards. This leads to a time-limited approach instead of a generalized resolution. E.g. I may state that this method is superior for brewing now (maybe a fashionable thing); in two years another method might shadow the first (or a new fashion). I cannot stop thinking bulletproof coffee at this point. Half of the questions were on it five years ago. Anyone drinks it in these days?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your patience in getting this change enacted here. I've changed the site setting for the Main Coffee site for you as of just now. If at some point in the future you want to go back to pinning accepted answers, please start a new meta discussion about it and flag it for our attention with the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag.

I've only changed this on the main site, not on meta as well - most sites have only wanted to change this on main. If you'd like to also unpin accepted answers on meta, please let us know.